# Developing WYSIWYG UI/Controller on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, wysiwyg

I'm trying to develop a really good and cute looking text message input controller like TTMessageController from three20 but with some simple WYSIWYG controls. For the first step I want to go super-simple and make it have Bod Italic and underlines only.

I know it's a very general question but I want to hear...

1. What are the approaches of making WYSIWYG editors and text message controller on iPhone?
2. Are there some open source examples?
3. What iPhone app do have good examples of such controller?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: Yes, this question is so old that Apple introduced 3.2 SDK with CoreText framework, which can provide APIs for rich text manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

On iOS >=4 you can use an UIWebView with designMode and contentEditable. In previous versions you can do a mix between native code and interpreted javascript/dom manipulation.